# Network printer remains in deep sleep, is processing but not printing

Tags: networking, suspend, printing

- Printer: Brother HL-L2350DW
- WLAN adress ok, like 192.168.1.169, ping ok
- accepts print job but stuck in processing
- printer display remains in deep sleep

CUPS:

- Driver:   Brother HL-L2350DW series, driverless, cups-filters 1.28.15 (grayscale, 2-sided printing)
- Connection:   ipp://Brother%20HL-L2350DW%20series._ipp._tcp.local/
- Defaults: job-sheets=none, none media=iso_a4_210x297mm sides=two-sided-long-edge.

iPAD:

- Under iPADOS 15.6.1 / Brother iPrint&Scan I could register the printer HL-L2350DW as a network printer. With share - print I could print a pdf-file with normal delay. At the same time, older queued print jobs from Jammy 22.04 were finally printed, too.
- Until then, the display on the printer reported "deep sleep".
- Apparently the printer cannot be woken up by Ubuntu but successfully with iPADOS.

Any help?

Unpredictable!

Sometimes the printer works just fine, sometimes the print job is stuck in the queue.
I have no idea what to do!

Comment: What happens when you try to print from different networked devices, preferably not running Ubuntu? If you haven't tested it yet then please do - you should have done that prior to posting a question like this - and [edit] to update your question accordingly. Surely you have an Android or iOS phone you can use for that troubleshooting even if you don't have other desktop computers.

Comment: [edit] your question with information concerning what you have researched and tried so far and the results so that they aren't duplicated.

Comment: edited my question, see above.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I have an HL-L2375DW. It has been problematic compare to other Brother color ink-jet printers in their line-up. You can't tame unless you call the Brother service center and force them fix the problem! Update firmware by windows computer and connect directly via USB, it might work for a while.

Comment: Thank you, Sadaharu. 
1) oh dear, having to *force* a service center ... Sadly, you'r probably right.
2) But will the printer via USB  be accessible in my homenet?